# Certain characters (like ț and ș) become question marks as I type them in a Tkinter Entry box

Tags: python, tkinter, input, unicode, character

Whenever I try typing ț or ș, they become question marks, but when I paste them in, they are shown correctly.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Entry(root).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I tried typing this at the top of the program: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-. I tried using different fonts. I can't figure it out.

Comment: @BryanOakley Did you type those characters (through a Romanian keyboard layout)? As I said before, pasting them works, but typing them doesn't.

Comment: I've tried various fonts: Roboto, Arial, DejaVu Sans, and Times New Roman, but ț and ș still get turned into question marks. Since these fonts support those characters, this leads me to think it might be something with Tkinter.

Comment: What is your platform? What keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: @relent95 I am on Windows, I have tried the Romanian Standard and Romanian Programmers keyboard layouts.

Comment: At last, I found a remedy for this problem. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug of Tcl/Tk on Windows. What about reporting on [this](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/ticket)? There are similar bugs for other languages. I reviewed [the current implementation](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/core-8-7-a5/win/tkWinX.c#L1440) for converting the key code, and found they should use the `PeekMessageW()` and `GetMessageW()`, instead of `PeekMessageA()` and `GetMessageA()`.

You can remedy this problem by filtering key events. The following is an example for Romanian standard keyboard.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)

REMEDIED_CHARS_STD = {ord(c): c for c in 'ȘșȚț'}
def on_key_press(e):
    char = REMEDIED_CHARS_STD.get(e.keysym_num)
    if char:
        e.widget.insert('insert', e.char[:-1] + char)
        return 'break'
entry.bind('<KeyPress>', on_key_press)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The same remedy can be applied for a Text widget, like the following.

```
...
text = tk.Text(root)
text.bind('<KeyPress>', on_key_press)
text.pack()
...
```

The following is an example of filtering for both Romanian standard keyboard and programmers keyboard.

```
...
REMEDIED_CHARS_STD = {ord(c): c for c in 'ȘșȚț'}
REMEDIED_CHARS_PROG = {ord('s'): 'șȘ', ord('t'): 'țȚ'}
def on_key_press(e):
    if e.keycode == 0x12: # VK_MENU
        e.widget.mods = e.state
    elif e.keycode == 0x10: # VK_SHIFT
        e.widget.mods |= 1 # ShiftMask
    elif e.type == tk.EventType.KeyPress:
        char = REMEDIED_CHARS_STD.get(e.keysym_num)
        if not char and e.char.endswith('?'):
            chars = REMEDIED_CHARS_PROG.get(e.keysym_num)
            if chars:
                shift = e.widget.mods & 1 # ShiftMask
                caps_lock = e.widget.mods & 2 # LockMask
                char = chars[bool(shift) ^ bool(caps_lock)]
        if char:
            e.widget.insert('insert', e.char[:-1] + char)
            return 'break'
entry.bind('<KeyPress>', on_key_press)
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel obliged to mention to who sees this question in the future that this fix works on the Romanian Standard keyboard (where ; should type ș), but not on the Programmers one (where ș is types alt + s)

Comment: @IceTheDev2, I added an example for Romanian programmers keyboard.